# nested for loop time complexity with function calls

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
 for(i = 1; i < a; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < b; j = j + 3){
      if((i+j) % 2 == 0)
          Func()
 }
}
```

In this case, I thought it is `O(a*b)` and `Theta(a*b)`.

Did I analyze the Complexity correctly?

Comment: Eh, `i` is *positive*, `j % 2` is *non-negative*, so `i+j % 2` is a *positive* and *never* equals to `0`; thus `Func()` will never be executed. Do you mean `(i + j) % 2 == 0`?

Comment: It is (i+j)%2 == 0, sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you, probably, mean

```
 if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
```

instead of

```
 if (i + j % 2 == 0)
```

since when `i` is *positive*, `j % 2` *non-negative* then `i + j % 2` is *positive* and thus `i + j % 2` *never* equals to zero: `Func()` doesn't run at all.

Your answer is correct one: the complexity is

```
 a *      // from the first loop
 b / 3 *  // from the second loop
 1        // from the condition (it always true)
```

So you have

```
 Θ(a * b / 3 * 1) = Θ(ab)
```